# Combine multiple Linq Where statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I've created a function to filter and sort the content of a list.

It's seems a bit 'bitty', however Linq isn't strong point. I'm wondering if the function can be streamlined, either from a performance perspective or even asthetic perspective.

Here's the code:

// Deserialise the XML to create a class of active rows

```
    var agents = XmlHelper
        .Deserialise<AgentConfigs>("~/Pingtree.xml")
        .Agents
        .Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
```

// First - get 'direct' agents and order them

```
    var direct = agents
        .Where(x => x.IsDirect)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.MinPrice);
```

// Second - get indirect agents and order them

```
    var agency = agents
        .Where(x => !x.IsDirect)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Priority);
```

// Bolt the 2 sublists together, retaining the order

```
    Agents = direct.Concat(agency).ToList();
```

Any thoughts on how this could be improved?

Comment: Shopuld probably go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the solution is working fine,and you want improvement/review of how it can be constructed better, post to http://stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: First off you iterate the same enumerations multiple times which is marked by Resharper e.g. This MAY cause performance-issues and can easily be avoided by calling `.ToList` on your agents before performing further queries.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: OP is not executing the query until the final `ToList`. Due the nature of deferred execution on the involved LINQ methods it is only enumerated once. Your approach with calling `ToList` two times forces the query to be evalated two times.

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, I ment calling `ToList` after the first call mentioned in the post, not after the other ones.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: ok, that's a good idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` or `ToLookup` to split both, i prefer `ToLookup` in this case:

```
var activeAgentDirectLookup = XmlHelper
    .Deserialise<AgentConfigs>("~/Pingtree.xml")
    .Agents
    .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
    .ToLookup(a => a.IsDirect);

Agents = activeAgentDirectLookup[true].OrderByDescending(x => x.MinPrice)
    .Concat(activeAgentDirectLookup[false].OrderBy(x => x.Priority))
    .ToList();
```

A [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx) is similar to a dictionary with a `bool` as key in this case(so two possible groups). The values are `IEnumerable<Agents>`, so all agents which are either `IsDirect` or `!IsDirect`. The benefit here is that you only need to evaluate it once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. I'm a littled baffled by the code - please could you annotate what the bits do.

Comment: A lookup is similar to a dictionary with a `bool` as key(so two possible groups). The values are `IEnumerable<Agents>`, so all agents which are either `IsDirect` or `!IsDirect`. The benefit here is that you only need to evaluate it once.

Comment: Ah, get ya now - nice solution!